# NodeJS Core Modules not appearing in External Libraries (WebStorm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, configuration, webstorm

I am extremely new to NodeJS and WebStorm, I'm currently following a tutorial for an Express app.

In the tutorial, whenever he creates a new NodeJs Express app, he is prompted with "Configure NodeJS Core Module Sources" where the URL nodeJS.org appears - this stage does not happen for me - it just goes ahead and creates the project.

This means that my "External Libraries" Folder is empty, when it should have all of the NodeJS Core Modules in it.

Is there a step I am missing?

Any and all help will be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'Local' libraries (files/folders located in project directory and configured as libraries, like `node_modules`), as well as **Node.js Core** library, don't appear in '**External libraries**'. 
To check if **Node.js Core** library is set up, open `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM` - do you see `Node.js Core Library is enabled` there?

[image]

Comment: Yeah it's there and enabled! Guess that's that then - just couldn't understand why mine was different than the tutorial! - many thanks for the reply!

Comment: After clicking "Enable" it s displays "configuring ..." and nothing changes :(

Comment: IDE version? Node.js version? Please provide your idea.log

Comment: When using IDE version 2018.1.5 with node version 10.6.0 your solution does not work.